# Why didn't Russia invade Ukraine during the Olympic games?

Tags: russian-federation, geopolitics

I am wondering why the timing is so strange, because Russia said it wouldn't invade Ukraine, and didn't do so until recently right after the Olympic Games ended.

Is there a reason for this? Did they want to do it so that the media is focused on the current events instead of the Olympics, or is there some other more specific motivations that might have led to this strange timing?

Comment: I suspect the only one who could answer this question is Vladimir Putin, and I don't think he frequents this site.  Anyone else would just be speculating - though such speculation might be informative.

Comment: It's not just speculation. I don't think any country invaded another country during the Olympics games, especially if they were attending the events. There has to be a very specific reason for this.

Comment: [Putin himself invaded Georgia the very day the 2008 Summer Olympics opened](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russo-Georgian_War).

Comment: I think it is coincidence.

Comment: The IOC has condemned Russia for violating the Olympic truce. The games are not over until the Paraolympics are complete.

Comment: Diplomacy wasn't finished yet. What do Olympics have to do with wars? Nothing I think.

Comment: Why do you think the media would be focused on the Olympics instead of Ukraine? Also I would think that the Olympics would get suspended/stopped for the conflict.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the winter Olympics were held in Beijing and Putin needs the support of China to get away with the potential sanctions from Western.(See my answer [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/71035/41884))

China really wanted the winter Olympics to be held successfully without any external harassments, so that they could leave a "positive image" to the world, noticing that the Olympics were already diplomatically boycotted by many countries. This arrangement could be part of the talk between Xi and Putin on Feb 4 when they signed the deal (again see link above).

Comment: This answer is s bit speculative. It offers a motivation but no evidence for its claims. It would be better if it would use "would" or "could" in all places that are not covered by external sources

Comment: Especially since Putin did launch a war during the 2008 Olympics that were held in Beijing...